# How to revoke permission of Windows Administrator user from DB2?

Tags: db2

On IBM DB2 v.9 windows, when someone connect to database by Server\Administrator user
DB2 database will automatically accept and grant all the permissions to this user?
But, in some case environment Administrator of server does not need to see every data in the database. So how to prevent Administrator use connect to database?

Answer (score 1):

On 9.5 and older this would not be possible because the account under which your instance runs is SYSADM. Also Administrator can reset at least local account passwords and gain access to them, making changing the instance owner account useless.

However on 9.7 and onwards the instance owner will not have access to the data anymore. One option is to upgrade to 9.7. Furthermore you can set up an AD account for the connections your applications use. Local Administrator is not necessarily able to change into those credentials.

Still, the Administrator ultimately has access to the (usually unencrypted) database files. You can mostly improve the administrative aspect of security.

Answer (score 0):

By default, DB2 databases are created with `CONNECT` authority granted to public.  If you want to restrict some users from connecting, you need to do

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE TO <user1>, <user2>, ...
```

Then revoke the CONNECT authority from PUBLIC

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE FROM PUBLIC
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm... For many times I try to revoke with this command but when I connect to database by Administrator account DB2 will automatic grant permission to Administrator again.

I will try again for make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible under normal circumstances simply because Administrator is in the `sysadm` group.

Options I can think of (but haven't tried) include:

- Setting the sysadm group to something else ("db2 update dbm cfg using sysadm_group blah").  Check the docs for caveats and gotchas when doing this, as I'm sure there are some.
- Stop using OS authentication.  Use a different security plugin (8.2 and higher only).  This would move the authentication, and thus groups, to a new location (say an LDAP server).  Then you just don't add Administrator to the new location, and especially don't add Administrator to the sysadm group again.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the database manager configuration parameter `SYSADM_GROUP` controls who has `SYSADM`authority at the instance level.  When `SYSADM_GROUP` is blank (as is the default on Windows), then DB2 defaults to using the Administrators group on the local machine.

To fix this, you can create a new group in Windows and then modify the value of `SYSADM_GROUP` to use this new group.  Make sure that the ID that the DB2 Service runs under belongs to this new group.  After making this change, members of the Administrators group will no longer have `SYSADM` authority.

As Kevin Beck states, you may also want to look at restricting `CONNECT` authority on databases, too, because by default the `CONNECT` privilege is granted to PUBLIC.